# How can I add color to the current git branch in my bash PROMPT?

Tags: linux, bash, git, terminal

I'm trying to add some color, in my terminal prompt, to the current git branch.

My prompt :

```
export PS1="
\e[32m\u@\h \e[36m\w \`parse_git_branch\`
\\e[0m$ "
```

So as you could probably guess, it displays something like that :
`user@host path/to/dir [git branch[ !]]`.
[git branch] is displayed only if the current folder is a git directory. The exclamation mark `!` is displayed only if there are changes on the current branch.

So, I would like to add color (red) to the git branch, but only if there are changes to it. I can't add `\e[31m` just before the `parse_git_branch` function in the prompt declaration, because it doesn't give me the possibility to use the default color when their are no changes, the name of the branch would always be displayed in red.

So I have to modify the function itself. Here it is :

```
function parse_git_branch() {
        BRANCH=`git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'`
        if [ ! "${BRANCH}" == "" ]
        then
                STAT=`parse_git_dirty`
                echo "[${BRANCH}${STAT}]"
        else
                echo ""
        fi
}
```

I tried loads of different things. Like declaring the color `\033[31m` right before `[${BRANCH}${STAT}]` in the `echo` statement. The problem with doing it that way is that, like before, the color will also be red when there are no changes.

And here is the `parse_git_dirty` function :

```
function parse_git_dirty {
        status=`git status 2>&1 | tee`
        dirty=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "modified:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
        untracked=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "Untracked files" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
        ahead=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "Your branch is ahead of" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
        newfile=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "new file:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
        renamed=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "renamed:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
        deleted=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "deleted:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
        bits=''
        if [ "${renamed}" == "0" ]; then
                bits=">${bits}"
        fi
        if [ "${ahead}" == "0" ]; then
                bits="*${bits}"
        fi
        if [ "${newfile}" == "0" ]; then
                bits="+${bits}"
        fi
        if [ "${untracked}" == "0" ]; then
                bits="?${bits}"
        fi
        if [ "${deleted}" == "0" ]; then
                bits="x${bits}"
        fi
        if [ "${dirty}" == "0" ]; then
                bits="!${bits}"
        fi
        if [ ! "${bits}" == "" ]; then
                echo " ${bits}"
        else
                echo ""
        fi
}
```

What do you suggest I should try ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are running `parse_git_dirty` and pretty much appending it to the branch name. Instead, you can provide a branch name to the function and wrap it with different "color code" strings based on the status.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I'm correct, you're telling me that I should add a condition that checks : `if ["${STAT}" == "!"]` and if it does, add the color ?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

This will change your prompt to display not only your working directory but also your current git branch.

```
export PS1="\\w:\$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 2)\$ "
```